# Oracle - Materialized Views on Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, view

From documents i understood that we cant create materialized views on query that have subquery in it.
So i created a normal oracle view and using that normal view i created a materialized view

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  TEST_MV BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FORCE  AS 
SELECT * FROM "MAIN_LOOKUP"
```

This "MAIN_LOOKUP" view have many sub queries in it

Help me understand below point

1. The "Main Look up" View have the tables that will be used real time and high chances of data change .Since the option is specified as FORCE will it automatically refreshed?
2. i couldn't include the option ENABLE QUERY REWRITE its saying "expression not supported for query rewrite".if am not specifying the option will it be any problem to the MV created?
3. Should we have the materialized view log created for all the underlying tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-MATERIALIZED-VIEW.html#GUID-EE262CA4-01E5-4618-B659-6165D993CA1B):

> Specify FORCE to indicate that when a refresh occurs, Oracle Database
> will perform a fast refresh if one is possible or a complete refresh
> if fast refresh is not possible.

This specifies which type of refresh will happen: fast (incremental) refresh if possible, otherwise full refresh. It will *not* refresh anything automatically.

The `ON COMMIT` option will update the MV automatically, but will significantly impact application performance if the source tables are highly active:

> Specify ON COMMIT to indicate that a refresh is to occur whenever the
> database commits a transaction that operates on a master table of the
> materialized view. This clause may increase the time taken to complete
> the commit, because the database performs the refresh operation as
> part of the commit process.

In other words, this would serialize all transactions on all of your source tables, forcing an MV refresh for each commit on each table.

Query Rewrite is not enabled by default, so not including it won't affect anything. If you *want* to have it enabled, then it must meet the following criteria:

> Enabling of query rewrite is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> You can enable query rewrite only if all user-defined functions in the
> materialized view are DETERMINISTIC.
>
> You can enable query rewrite only if expressions in the statement are
> repeatable. For example, you cannot include CURRENT_TIME or USER,
> sequence values (such as the CURRVAL or NEXTVAL pseudocolumns), or the
> SAMPLE clause (which may sample different rows as the contents of the
> materialized view change).

Create MV Logs on the source tables if your MV meets the criteria for FAST REFRESH. You will still have to refresh the MV manually, or using a scheduled job.

> FAST refresh is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - When you specify FAST refresh at create time, Oracle Database verifies
>   that the materialized view you are creating is eligible for fast
>   refresh. When you change the refresh method to FAST in an ALTER
>   MATERIALIZED VIEW statement, Oracle Database does not perform this
>   verification. If the materialized view is not eligible for fast
>   refresh, then Oracle Database returns an error when you attempt to
>   refresh this view.
> - Materialized views are not eligible for fast refresh if the defining
>   query contains an analytic function or the XMLTable function.
> - Materialized views are not eligible for fast refresh if the defining
>   query references a table on which an XMLIndex index is defined.
> - You cannot fast refresh a materialized view if any of its columns is
>   encrypted.

There are several additional restrictions from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/basic-materialized-views.html#GUID-505C24CF-5D56-4820-88AA-2221410950E7) on the use of fast refresh materialized views, many of which are conditional. Do your homework and read up on the requirements and exceptions to determine if they will work in your specific situation. For practical examples, you can also check a variety of online tutorials and examples, like [this one](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/materialized-views).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will FAST refresh expect the primary key on the source table?

Comment: Fast refresh can also work using ROWID (in fact it may be required), but you need to read up on all of the other restrictions and requirements in the documentation. I've added a couple more links to my answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Am createing a MV which inturn uses another MV .Doing this because MV doesnt support subquery.so how does the referesh happen ? both MV the master and the Child MV is defined as FAST and ON COMMIT

Comment: I would _strongly_ discourage the use of layered `ON COMMIT` materialized views, especially if the source tables are active. ON COMMIT means that _every_ transaction on a source table will trigger a refresh of every layered MV, and that multiple concurrent transactions will likely end up waiting on other MV refreshes to finish before they can start. This will almost certainly affect your application performance in a very, very bad way, even using FAST refresh. From a performance/scalability perspective, you would be better off using a scheduled job to refresh once per minute.

Comment: Also consider that if something goes wrong with the ON COMMIT refresh at any layer, it will force your application transaction to fail and rollback. Is your application designed to handle that? If you really need real-time access to the changed data, then I would recommend using a normal view rather than a materialized view.  What is the driving decision behind your use of materialized views?

Comment: our application is now using the normal views.we are developing a new application in which we except the response in milliseconds and hence we thought of using MV . Yes as you suggested we will go with option of ON DEMAND and refresh it in certain interval.MV is faster than normal view  correct?

Comment: An MV _can_ be faster, yes. It depends on what kind of functions or aggregation the view is performing. What causes the traditional view to be slow?

Comment: We didnt investigate further on that .                                                                   
 SELECT id,NAME || '~' || col1|| '|' colfinal, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col2 ASC) RNK_NO
FROM Table A .                                                                                                                                                        when we creater materialized view on this am unable to create with FAST option .it says the "WIndow function in MV"